# Add toggle button dynamically in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to add a toggle button dynamically. The toggle button will look like in [Flip toggle switch Example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/). I tried like that but i get a different output like `data-role="slider"` is not working. the code

```
$('button').click( function() {
   var element  =  $ ('#test');
    var toggle_button = '<select data-role="slider"><option value="off">Off</option><option value="on">On</option></select>';
    element.append(toggle_button);
});
```

My JsFiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/4Fk9L/1/

What I do wrong here?

Comment: I think you'll have to call the $('select').slider(); because you are adding it after the DOM is ready

Comment: Yep.. thats the solution. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the switch function after the element is appended..

```
 $('button').click( function() {
    var element  =  $ ('#test');
    var toggle_button = '<select data-role="slider"><option value="off">Off</option>   <option value="on">On</option></select>';
    element.append(toggle_button);
    $('select').slider();  //call plugin function here
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4Fk9L/2/

Comment: I was first ;) http://jsfiddle.net/4Fk9L/1/ haha (note the /1) lol i have no idea why im telling xD